# One click displays lightbox, but only a second click hides it (not the same first click)

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm trying to generate a simple lightbox when clicking on images. Then clicking anywhere will destroy this lightbox.

Problem: everything is executed at once, even the destroying part. Here's my code:

```
$('img').on('click', function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="gray"><div id="gray_content"></div></div>');
    var image = $(this).clone();
    $('#gray_content').html(image);
    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#gray').remove();
    });
});
```

How to execute the remove() part on a SECOND click from the user (not the same first click)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple flag for this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv4hzsne/).

```
var isFirst = true;

$('img').on('click', function()
{
    if (isFirst)
    {
        $('body').append('<div id="gray"><div id="gray_content"></div></div>');
        var image = $(this).clone();
        $('#gray_content').html(image);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#gray').remove();
    }
    isFirst = !isFirst;
});
```

**Update**. To be able to remove by clicking anywhere, you can use:

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jv4hzsne/1/).

```
var isFirst = true;

$('img').on('click', function()
{
    if (isFirst)
    {
        $('body').append('<div id="gray"><div id="gray_content"></div></div>');
        var image = $(this).clone();
        $('#gray_content').html(image);
        isFirst = false;
        return false;
    }
});

$(document).on('click', function()
{
    if (!isFirst)
    {
        $('#gray').remove();
        isFirst = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: in this case the second click is only captured for the image, but I  guess @drake wants it removed if users click anywhere on the document.  you might want to move the isFirst to global scope and set/unset it based on the   bubbled up click event on document object....    $(document).click(function() { isFirst=!First;});

Answer (score 0):

You almost never want to bind one event handler inside another handler. In your code, every time you click on an image, you're adding ANOTHER click handler to the document. You should just bind that handler once at top level. You don't need to wait until after the first handler runs -- if the `gray` DIV hasn't been added to the DOM, there just won't be anything to remove.

```
$(":not(img)").click(function() {
    $("#gray").remove();
});
$("img").click(function() {
    if ($("#gray").length == 0) { // If it's not already showing
        $('body').append('<div id="gray"><div id="gray_content"></div></div>');
    }
});
```

The reason clicking on the image destroys the `gray` DIV is because of event bubbling -- after the click  handler on the image runs, the event bubbles out to the document and that event handler also runs. You could prevent bubbling by putting `event.stopPropagation()` in the image click handler.

BTW, adding and removing elements like this is generally considered a poor approach. It's usually preferable to use `.hide()` and `.show()`.